# Unable to form connection between ignite(v 2.7) node inside kubernetes-1.11.3

Tags: kubernetes, ignite

While starting one node it gets up with time delay around 50-60 sec. but when we scale deployment to 2-3 then those nodes are unable to connect to st node. 
Also getting below error on 2nd and 3rd node.

> ERROR TcpDiscoverySpi:586 - Failed to get registered addresses from IP
>   finder on start (retrying every 2000ms; change 'reconnectDelay' to
>   configure the frequency of retries). class
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiException: Failed to retrieve Ignite
>   pods IP addresses.    at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:172)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.registeredAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1900)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.resolvedAddresses(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:1848)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.sendJoinRequestMessage(ServerImpl.java:1049)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.joinTopology(ServerImpl.java:910)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl.spiStart(ServerImpl.java:391)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.TcpDiscoverySpi.spiStart(TcpDiscoverySpi.java:2020)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.GridManagerAdapter.startSpi(GridManagerAdapter.java:297)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.managers.discovery.GridDiscoveryManager.start(GridDiscoveryManager.java:939)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.startManager(IgniteKernal.java:1682)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteKernal.start(IgniteKernal.java:1066)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start0(IgnitionEx.java:2038)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance.start(IgnitionEx.java:1730)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start0(IgnitionEx.java:1158)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:678)
>     at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx.start(IgnitionEx.java:618)
>     at org.apache.ignite.Ignition.getOrStart(Ignition.java:415)     at
>   com.cloud.ignite.server.IgniteServer.startIgnite(IgniteServer.java:57)
>     at com.cloud.ignite.server.IgniteServer.(IgniteServer.java:39)
>     at
>   com.cloud.ignite.server.IgniteServer.getInstance(IgniteServer.java:107)
>     at com.cloud.ignite.server.IgniteServer.main(IgniteServer.java:133)
>   Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection
>   refused)  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)  at
>   sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:673)    at
>   sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:173)
>     at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)  at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:463)   at
>   sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:558)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.(HttpsClient.java:264)
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:367)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1156)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1050)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1564)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
>     at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:263)
>     at
>   org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.kubernetes.TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.getRegisteredAddresses(TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder.java:153)

Edits:

Below is configuration,

Namespace:dev (Same for client and server)

Service account: default

Master URL : default value

account token : Default Value

Code Snippet:

```
TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder podIpFinder = new TcpDiscoveryKubernetesIpFinder();
podIpFinder.setNamespace("DEV");

TcpDiscoverySpi tcpDiscoverySpi = new TcpDiscoverySpi();
tcpDiscoverySpi.setIpFinder(podIpFinder);

IgniteConfiguration igniteConfiguration = new IgniteConfiguration();
igniteConfiguration..setDiscoverySpi(tcpDiscoverySpi);

Ignite ignite = Ignition.getOrStart(igniteConfiguration);
```

Comment: Need more details: your Kubernetes and Ignite configs and the exact steps you take. How often does this issue occur? Also, if you can create a small reproducer for this it would be great.

Comment: @StanislavLukyanov edited question with more details

Answer (score -2):

first u

1. kubectl get pods --all-namespaces=true
2. get the pod name from the list and execute 
   kubectl --namespace fusion get  pods/podName

podName : the name of your pod.

Comment: I am getting my pod names correctly.Above issue is randomly occurring.So please elaborate your answer.